# Stubbing/Mocking/Spying a function within a function in dart

Tags: dart

I have been working with Dart for the past couple of days for some unit tests. I have been seeing weird functionality on testing a function within a function where I would mock one function to return something but it does not change the prior function. Code and output displayed below:

### Main Class:

```
class ToBeTested {
       int sum(int i, int z) {
                 return addOne(i) + z;
            }
            int addOne(int i) {
                 return i + 1;
            }
     }
```

### Test Created:

```
test("hello", () async{
         var ToBeTestedSpy = spy(new ToBeTested(), new ToBeTested(param1,param 2));
         print(ToBeTestedSpy.sum(5, 10));
         when(ToBeTestedSpy.addOne(5)).thenReturn(100);
         print(ToBeTestedSpy.sum(5, 10));
  });
```

Output: 
        16
        16

Why is the output not 
       16 
       110 
even after stubbing the spy to override its return to 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spy is deprecated in mockito.
Instead it is recommended to handcode part of your stub (or use code generation technique) (see https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/commit/dc8ce18d6e1096d2546d1ef5afe417cd9e042aee)

I'm not sure of what you want to do but this is what I came up with:

```
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

abstract class CalcInterface {
  int sum(int i, int z);
  int addOne(int i);
}

abstract class BaseCalc implements CalcInterface {
  int sum(int i, int z) {
    return addOne(i) + z;
  }
}

class Calc extends Object with BaseCalc implements CalcInterface {
  int sum(int i, int z) {
    return addOne(i) + z;
  }

  int addOne(int i) {
    return i + 1;
  }
}

class MockCalc extends Mock with BaseCalc implements CalcInterface {}

main() {
  test("hello", () {
    var mocked = new MockCalc();
    when(mocked.addOne(5)).thenReturn(100);

    expect(mocked.sum(5, 10), 110);

    verify(mocked.addOne(5)).called(1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Even though spying is deprecated. Is there a way to get the same results as above with a Spy stub? 

Otherwise are you recommending to create and interface and abstract class just to test the functionality in the Test Class?